# Android app to Xarmarin

Tags: java, c#

I was thinking about different ways to convert my android app to ios app without learning and writing code in obj C from scratch. So I thought about converting it to c# and using xarmarin, create the ios version of it.

I just wanted to know what's the best tool to convert java to c#. I know there is an old post but it's 10 years old, i was just wondering if there is an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be difficult. Especially for all UI specific code. There are some solutions to convert some part of your code such as model, controller or business logic.

You can use [Sharpen](https://github.com/mono/sharpen) to convert Java to C#. But, it will be difficult to use it for UI part. And even, if you achieve this, you will obtain a Xamarin application that targets Android only.
Of course, it will be easier to port your application to iOS but you will have to rewrite all UI code.

You can still try Xamarin, by porting your non UI code and creating a **Xamarin Forms application** (it means new UI code to develop) which can then be deployed on iOS and Android.

Comment: I have a month to port everything so i can write UI code myself :)